# Ubuntu Virtual Machine File Sharing -- Mounting

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, virtual-machine, automounting

I am running Windows 10 as my host OS, using Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 6.0.8 as my virtual machine software, and Ubuntu 18.04.2 is my guest OS. I am trying to set up folder and file sharing.

I went to the settings for my virtual machine (on Oracle VM VirtualBox) and created a new, shared folder. When setting it up I checked off auto-mounting and make permanent. However, when I open up my files in Ubuntu I see the folder but am unable to open it. When I click on it, I get an error that says: This location could not be displayed. Then in smaller letters underneath it says: you do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "*shared_folder_I_created*".

I was googling and came across this link: https://helpdeskgeek.com/virtualization/virtualbox-share-folder-host-guest/. It explained that to set up a shared folder I should do everything I did, but then to (additionally) run the following line in terminal:

```
mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint
```

Then it said:

> Replace sharename with the name of the share and mountpoint with the
>   path where you want the share to be mounted (i.e. `/mnt/share`).

This seems to indicate that I did not properly mount this folder, despite having checked off auto-mount when I originally created this folder.

Anyway, I tried running this in terminal but received an error:

```
mount: only root can use "--types" option
```

This seems like it might be a simple sudo fix. However, because I don't know what this command means, I wanted to first figure out what it does.

So really I have two questions:

1. What does each part of this command mean?
2. How do I fix the error I am receiving when I try to run it?

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint
```

`-t vboxsf` - pseudofilesystem that provides ***Shared folder mechanism between host and guest systems**. You should install **guest additions** before use this filesystem. Helpful tutorial about guest additions installation is located at this [link](https://www.tecmint.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/).

`-o OPTIONS` - list of options that can help or specify behaviour of mounted resource (i.e. `uid`, `gid` ...). Set of this option depends on type of filesystem that you mount.

`sharename` - name/source of resource that should be mounted (name of shared folder in your case).

`mountpoint` - destionation directory in which your resource will be available after mounting.

Full details about `mount` command you can achieve from [man 8 mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).

More info about `vboxsf` and their `OPTIONS` you can achieve from [man 8 mount.vboxsf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mount.vboxsf.8.html).

---

Yout should `mount` resources with superuser privileges. So you should being `root` user or run `mount` in `sudo mount ...` style.

Read more about `sudo` in [man 8 sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).